# Отсутствие перевода сообщений при предложении закрытия вопроса как дубликата существующего

Tags: дефект, локализация, дубликаты

Надо бы перевести эти сообщения:

> Some community members have suggested a similar question that may solve your problem.

> Thanks! Edit your question to explain how it’s different from the suggested questions. This will help prevent your question from getting closed and will remove the suggested questions notification from your post.

[image: скриншот]

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 4):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13672
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13669

Ждём свежих сборок. Текущая rev 2020.8.10.37369

Comment: А там рядом нет ещё одной фразы на случай, если бы я нажал Да, а не Нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю. Надо нажать и посмотреть что там за фраза.